# Unable to receive data from Volley's response (asynchronous call)

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley as HTTP library to handle my web communication and it works perfectly fine as every respone I generally handle is either JSON or String.

The only thing that I'm having issues with is a particular call that responds with a JSON array, which gets parsed correctly but I can't return the "parsed" value, as the return happens before the call is completed, ending up as `null`.

Here's some code:

```
private ArrayList <User> users;

public ArrayList<User> searchUser(final String usernamestart){

    users= new ArrayList<>();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String serverResponse) {
            parseUsers(serverResponse);
            // see following snippet
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to retrieve data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        // parameters of POST request
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("session_id", session_id);
            params.put("usernamestart", usernamestart);

            return params;
        }
    };//closes string request

    VolleyQueue.add(request);
    return users;
}
```

to parse the response, and works perfectly fine, I'm using:

```
private void parseUsers(String jsonResponse){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONArray array= jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");

        for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject pointedUser= array.getJSONObject(i);
            String username= pointedUser.getString("name");
            String picture= pointedUser.getString("picture");

            users.add(new User(username, picture));
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The issue is that the `return users` happens before the call is completed. I can't return the ArrayList `users` inside `onResponse` as it's a void method... I can't really find any solutions to this.

I have tried also a synchronous call but that's not what I want. What I would like is a Volley method that notifies me when the call is executed, but it's not something that's implemented yet.
Hope someone can help me without drastically having to change my asset!

Answer (score 0):

This is an async call, you cannot return value using `return()` expression.
you already got `users` in `parseUsers` method, just use it as you want.

```
 return users; //delete this line, or the searchUser function will return to the caller before received response.
```

Comment: since searchUsers is the function that gets called in my Activity, its result is what I can handle in the Activity. parseUsers is a private method, so adding "return" wouldn't solve my problem because it would return it inside OnResponse, where I cannot make any use of it